# Adding text to registration form

Tags: user, login, registration

I am running Joomla 3.6 and I just want to add some informational text at the top of the registration form. I have seen suggestions about language overrides but that doesn't mean anything to me. With the login form you can add text above and below. Is there not someting similar for the registration form? If not can somebody please explain how I can add some text without the danger of it dissapearing when I update. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you can do for that (both are safe from Joomla update / you won't loose the changes when updating your Joomla)

**1. By using template override**

Copy the file */components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php*

to

*/templates/your_template_name/html/com_users/registration/default.php*

then open it with your favorite php editor. 
Arround lines 29-32 you will see this code :

```
<?php if (isset($fieldset->label)): ?>
        <legend><?php echo JText::_($fieldset->label);?></legend>
<?php endif;?>
```

Simply add your text after that code, so it would become like this :

```
<?php if (isset($fieldset->label)): ?>
        <legend><?php echo JText::_($fieldset->label);?></legend>
<?php endif;?>
<p>This is your additional text</p>
```

**2. By using language override**

I'm not sure why you are thinking the language override won't work, but you can try these steps below (this indeed a bit tricky but it should be simple and you can do this if you don't want to touch the code)

Go to **Extensions > Languges > Override(s)** from your Administrator page.
Click on the **New** Button then search COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_DEFAULT_LABEL in the search form in the right of page and set the **Search for** to **Constant**.
Click on the result item then you will see in the left side, string to override.

Change the text 'User registration' to this :

```
User Registration </legend> <p>This is your additional text</p><legend>
```

[image]

Comment: This was just what I wanted and it works perfectly. Very clearly explained.